# Blank line in my bash.history?

Tags: bash, history

I was taking a look at my `.bash_history`, and I found a blank line.
I thought that I could have pressed "enter" while I was taking a look in the file.

Is that normal? Or maybe I really pressed enter while looking the file on gedit?

EDIT: Just found today that I have more than one line break. That's strange, I never edit the .bash_history file.

Comment: i just had a look at my .bash_history file. It has around 700 commands but not a single line break. it sure seems like a mispress of the enter key, but cannot completely vouch on it..

Comment: In my file, I have aprox 1000 lines, and only 1 line break.

Comment: i have noticed that when i edit a file in gedit, a backup file with the name as `<original file name>~` is created in the same directory. so can you check and report if you find `.bash_history~` file and if yes, do you see the blank line there too?

Comment: I used the command 'gedit .bash_history~', but it created a new file. Also, strangely, now everytime that I open a folder, I can always see a hidden file or folder (like if I pressed Ctrl + h)

Comment: @astrobOt Right now, I fixed the bugs that I could always see hidden files (no idea how it activated).

Comment: its not strange that 'gedit .bash_history~' created a new file. It was just a thing that i had noticed and thought that might help us debug.Nothing to worry about that. But i am not sure if one should be bothered about a line break in the .bash_history file. i intentionally inserted multiple blank lines and played around with cli and didn't experience anything weird.

Comment: @astrob0t Besides the "auto showing hidden files", nothing wrong happened.

Comment: @astrob0t Sorry for this update, but I just noticed that I have multiple blank lines in my file. Should I still be worried about it?

Comment: i am not aware of any security implications in this situation. you should try to [seek help at chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room). maybe someone can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a problem, it is not dangerous and is entirely normal. You can get such lines if you hit <kbd>space</kbd> a few times and then hit <kbd>enter</kbd>. This will be saved in your history (since it is a non-blank line, spaces are characters just invisible ones).

To test this, we can use a command that prints the blank lines in bash's history For example, this `grep` will match all lines that start with numbers and then have 0 or more whitespace (spaces or tabs or whatever) and nothing else until the end of the line:

```
history | grep -P '^\s*\d+\s*$'
```

That should show you a list of empty commands you have run. Now, run ( the first line means hit space a few times, then enter)

```
$ echo foo
foo
$       
$ history  | tail -n 3
$ history | tail -n 3
80  echo foo
81               ## this is the blank line
82  history | tail -n 3
```

You will notice that you have a new blank line. In conclusion, don't worry. everything is fine and this is normal.

Answer (score 1):

As [mentioned by terdon](https://askubuntu.com/a/551880/52975), those are likely whitespace only lines.

There are two environment variables options that control whether whitespace lines are stored in the history or not:

- `HISTCONTROL`: if it contains `ignorespace`, then any line that starts with a whitespace is ignored.
- `HISTIGNORE`: colon separated list of pattens to ignore. For example, if it contains:

  ```
  HISTIGNORE=' *'
  ```

  then lines that start with a single space will be ignored.

I was not able to make bash store truly empty lines without whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://askubuntu.com/a/679768/455894) is an explanation about how blank lines can occur in the `.bash_history` file.

In brief:

> If you call from the history a command line that you have actually typed earlier **in that same current terminal session** and then edit it (maybe deleting it) but then interrupt your edit by leaving that (history-)command line using for instance the `Down` arrow to come back to the prompt of the actual current command line, then when later on you exit the terminal the edits get recorded in the .bash_history file.