# How to prevent commands being removed from history?

Tags: command-line, bash, history

I have noticed that when I go up through my commands using the arrow keys, <kbd>UP</kbd> and <kbd>DOWN</kbd>, that if I then edit a command, it edits it in history, and I can even remove a command like that, however I do not want it to have this affect on the commands in history, I don't want it to actually delete them in the history, only allow me to edit what I am typing, but not actually modify the history through this. So how can I make it so that this does not actually modify the history, but just the command that I execute?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I asked something quite similar in Unix & Linux: [How to undo changes in the commands-history?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/199598/40596).

The [great answer I got from Gilles](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/199751/40596) says:

> As long as you've edited a history entry but not pressed
>   <kbd>Enter</kbd> yet, to go back to the original entry, repeatedly
>   press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>_</kbd> — the `undo` command — until it
>   doesn't make any further change. You're back to the original entry.

Comment: So is there no way to disable the feature which means you are allowed to edit and delete previous entries?

Comment: If you check the information with `history`, you will see it stores the initial info. So the data that is being changed is not that one, but the one you access through the arrows (which I don't know where it is stored).

Comment: @fedorqui it's stored in your home directory in a file called .bash_history (if you're using bash)

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem and while I was playing around and struggling to understand what was happening, I just figured out the following:

If you call from the `history` a command line that you have actually typed earlier **in that same current terminal session** and then edit it (maybe deleting it) but then interrupt your edit by leaving that (history-)command line using for instance the `Down` arrow to come back to the prompt of the actual current command line, then later on when you exit the terminal the edits get recorded in the `.bash_history` file.

This behavior does not happen if you edit and interrupt your edit on a command line that was already recorded in the `.bash_history` file before you started the terminal session.

In other words, while a terminal session is open, the newly typed command lines are only kept in memory, not in the `.bash_history`. You can recall them using the `up` arrow or invoking the `history` commands, and you can edit them while the session is open (when invoking the `history`command, the lines of modified commands will then be indicated by an asterisk `*`). It's only when you exit the session that the commands of the session get recorded 'as is' in the `.bash_history` file, thereby keeping the last edits you have made on them before exiting the session.

See also the answer from *falconer* [there](https://askubuntu.com/a/390417/455894).